# SVA package: how many surrogate variables are enough?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am working on differentially expressed gene analysis using TCGA RNA-seq data. The data is from over 500 brain cancer patients, and I hope to see if there is any DE detected genes between those with and without seizure history. In my metadata, I have so many other variables that potentially influence the RNA-seq counts:gender, histologic types of tumor, tumor grade, family history, etc.. And so it is not surprising when I plotted PCA based on groups of seizure category there was no clustering at all.

So I am using SVA package to create surrogate variables to account for these variation, but I am not sure how many surrogate variables would be enough to adjust for this, and how I can check whether such variation is effectively removed after applying SVA. I did see that the number of significant genes increased a bit after I run SVA by creating 4 surrogate variables, but is this enough?